# View helper for Spring Boot and Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm new in Spring Boot and now we want to rewrite our old PHP application in Java using Spring Boot 2 and Thymeleaf 3 as template engine.

Our legacy app has hundreds of forms with thousands of input fields. For this we use a simple template helper that makes it quite simple to render the input fields, labels and container divs. A small example:

```
FormBuilder::addInputField("Close","close_time",$data->getClose_time());
```

Generates:

```
<tr>
    <th>Close:</th>
    <td><input type="text" name="close_time" id="close_time_id" size="30" value=""> </td>
</tr>
```

How can I achieve this in Spring and Thymeleaf?

Comment: Yes, we use Thymeleaf  v3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1. Use Thymeleaf fragments**

formBuilder.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<tr th:fragment="inputField (title, name, value)">
    <th th:text="${title}"> or can use [[${title}]]</th>
    <td><input type="text" th:name="${name}" 
               id="close_time_id" size="30" th:value="${value}"> </td>
</tr>
</body>
</html>
```

and then in your main layout you can use

```
<body>
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:replace="formBuilder::inputField ('Close','close_time', ${value})"></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

---

**Option 2. Use spring bean service**

Thymeleaf allows accessing beans registered at the Spring Application Context with the @beanName syntax ([more info](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html)), for example:

```
<div th:text="${@formBuilder.addInputField('Close','close_time')}">...</div>
```

Comment: Both option works, thanks! 
One more thing I recognized, that it seems th:replace is working only with fragments but not with bean service. Is it possible with bean service to use it in a form like th:replace? I mean to eliminate the holder element in the output? So in the example above I don't want the holder div tag just the output of the bean service.

Comment: @Vmxes use `th:remove="tag"` to eliminate holder tag

Comment: or i think, you can just use http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#expression-inlining `[[${@formBuilder.addInputField('Close','close_time')}]]` without any tag